# What are the default iPad fonts

Tags: ipad, fonts

I want to use fonts that will work on web pages viewed on all recent iPads. I found lists of fonts that come with a given version of IOS. But that's not what I want. I prefer a list of fonts that actually comes with a given iPad, not version of IOS. How to figure this out?

Comment: You could start here: http://www.macosautomation.com/ipad/fonts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I prefer a list of fonts that actually comes with a given iPad, not version of IOS. How to figure this out?

That's not how it works.

Fonts are tied to the device's operating system, not the device itself.

An iPad will have whatever fonts come with the version of iOS that is installed on it.

To see which versions of iOS are supported by which device generation, check out the [iOS Version History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 6):

I always use this site to deal with fonts: http://iosfonts.com

It will help you.